# Как не загружать js дважды?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

Как предотвратить повторную загрузку файла с js? Например, на странице сайта Joomla несколько модулей с одинаковыми js-файлами. Можно ли проверять, загружен ли уже js в каком-либо модуле, и не загружать его в другом модуле? Конечно, можно перенести js в head, но он используется не на всех страницах сайта.

Answer (score 4):

На просторах enSO предлагают [такой вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26331789/6604614)

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var i = list.length;
while (i--) {
    if (list[i].src === 'filePathToJSScript') {
        break;
    }
}
```

**Для ES 6**

```js
let scripts = Array
    .from(document.querySelectorAll('script'))
    .map(scr => scr.src);

if (!scripts.includes('filePathToJSScript')) {
  // если не подключен ранее, выполнить код
}
```